# How to select a specific HTML element from identical nested divs

Tags: css, html

I need to select a specific HTML element, which are identical, also contain inside several identical `div`'s, I tried with `nth-child()` but it did not work. (Each child shares same properties with minor changes)

### HTML

```
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.disc .disc_PF:nth-child(1) {}
```

When I use this, it selects both first `disc_PF` elements,

### CSS

```
.disc .disc_PF:nth-child(2) {}
```

When I use this, it select third `disc_PF` element,

How can I select individual nested element separately?

Thanks

Comment: `.disc:first-child .disc_PF:first-child`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's how you could do it.

```css
.disc_PF
{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/* First .disc, all .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(1) > .disc_PF
{
  background: red;
}
/* Second .disc, first .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:first-child
{
  background: green;
}
/* Second .disc, .disc_PF that is the second child element */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:nth-child(2)
{
  background: yellow;
}
/* Second .disc, last .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:last-child
{
  background: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
</div>
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
  <div class="disc_PF">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for explanation, how can i select, if a parent has more than 2 children, ( how do you select intermediate child other than first one and last one)

Comment: Added an example for that case.

Answer (score 3):

Nth child starts counting from the element's parent, so if you have two elements from different parents where each is the second child of its own parent, you will be selecting both of them.

Try this:

```
.disc:nth-child(2) .disc_PF:nth-child(1) {}
```

Answer (score 2):

```css
.disc_PF
{
 width:100px;
 height:100px;
 float: left;
}

/* 1st .disc, all .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(1) > .disc_PF
{
  border:1px solid #ccc;
  background:#ccc;
}
/* 2nd .disc, 1st .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:first-child
{
  border:3px double #111;
}
/* 2nd .disc, 2nd .disc_PF  */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:nth-child(2)
{
  border:1px solid #0f0;
}
/* 2nd .disc, 3rd .disc_PF */
.disc:nth-of-type(2) > .disc_PF:last-child
{
  border:1px solid #00f;
}
```

```html
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  1st disc_PF
  </div>
</div>
<div class="disc">
  <div class="disc_PF">
  2nd disc_PF
  </div>
  <div class="disc_PF">
  3rd disc_PF
  </div>
  <div class="disc_PF">
  4th disc_PF
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`:nth-of-type()` and `:nth-child` only work on element names, not classnames. In other words,

```
.classname:nth-child(2)
```

doesn't work, but

```
div:nth-child(2)
```

does. Similarly, something like `.my-class:first-child()` will *not* select the first element with `.my-class` *unless* it's a first child.

Given your code example, the only options you have are either to add ids to the elements, or select any `<div>` based on it's position (first child, etc).